Are the select helper functions supported in oml4r dplyr
Should the select helper functions work in the transparency layer for oml4r dplyr.
I don’t think so because of what I show below,
> e <- ore.pull(EMP)
> e %>% select(contains("NO")) %>% print
     EMPNO DEPTNO
7369  7369     20
7499  7499     30
7521  7521     30
7566  7566     20
7654  7654     30
7698  7698     30
7782  7782     10
7788  7788     20
7839  7839     10
7844  7844     30
7876  7876     20
7900  7900     30
7902  7902     20
7934  7934     10
> emp <- ore.push(EMP)
> emp %>% select(contains("NO")) %>% print
Error in `eval_select_impl()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <ore.frame> object.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


Please read the description of the ML tag.
